# FMPI2C on STM32F407

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32f4

Is it possible to use Fast mode I2C on STM32F407 ?
I looked everywhere for the I2CX pins GPIO but Can't find them at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the right datasheet? Your headline talks about FMP or Fast Mode Plus, no it can't do that. However Fast Mode up to 400 kHz, definitely possible.

Comment: The  hal interface for Fast mode plus is exactly the same as general I2C on the STMF407, is it possible to use that hal with normal I2C mode ? with up 400khz ?

Comment: It can do Standard Mode up to 100 kHz and Fast Mode up to 400kHz with the HAL it has available. It can't do Fast Mode Plus which goes above 400 kHz.